# Bash: Move files to specific folder if name contains one of a list of strings

Tags: string, bash, shell, unix, mv

I have a script that queries the Twitter API for several queries, and then writes the raw data to a file with the query in the name, plus a timestamp. I'd like to have a script that, given the list of query strings (regexs?) and for all files in a folder, if one of the query strings is a substring in that file, move it to a specific folder. Right now I have just a script with just a few dozen `mv` commands, but I'd like a simpler and more maintainable version. Here's an example of what I'm doing now:

```
mv /home/nick/TwitterSearchToDatabase/queries_for_amita/*femin*/home/nick/TwitterSearchToDatabase/queries_for_amita/feminism
mv /home/nick/TwitterSearchToDatabase/queries_for_amita/*patriarchy* /home/nick/TwitterSearchToDatabase/queries_for_amita/feminism
mv /home/nick/TwitterSearchToDatabase/queries_for_amita/*yesallwomen* /home/nick/TwitterSearchToDatabase/queries_for_amita/feminism
mv /home/nick/TwitterSearchToDatabase/queries_for_amita/*womanpower* /home/nick/TwitterSearchToDatabase/queries_for_amita/feminism
```

Comment: You can do those moves in one command for a start. `mv glob1 glob2 glob3 dest`

Comment: For readability and maintainability, better save common segments of paths in shell parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a for loop:

```
for i in femin patriarchy yesallwomen womanpower; do
  mv /home/nick/TwitterSearchToDatabase/queries_for_amita/*$i* /home/nick/TwitterSearchToDatabase/queries_for_amita/feminism
done
```

That way the list is in the first line so it is easy to amend.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would isolate data (the words to be moved to feminism) and code.
When you have more keywords (feminism and so), you can make files with keywords and check these keywordfiles for the files you are considering to move.
With ${fromdir} where the files come from, ${todir} where you want them and ${keyfiledir} with the keywords, you get something like

```
for keyfile in ${keyfiledir}/*; do
   key="${keyfile##*/}"
   find $from -type f | sed 's#.*/##' | while read -r file; do
      echo "${file}" | grep -q -f "${keyfiledir}"/"${key}" && mv "${from}"/"${file}" "${to}"/"${key}"
   done
done
```

How does that work? I tested the solution above with the following script.

```
from=fromdir
to=todir
keyfiledir=keyfiledir
rm -rf ${from} ${to} ${keyfiledir}
mkdir ${from} ${to} ${keyfiledir}
mkdir ${to}/feminism ${to}/so
touch ${from}/yesallwomen ${from}/women ${from}/some_femin ${from}/"help move"
cat <<@ > ${keyfiledir}/feminism
femin
patriarchy
yesallwomen
womanpower
@
touch ${from}/yesallwomen ${from}/women ${from}/some_femin

cat <<@ > ${keyfiledir}/so
stack
exchange
help
@

test ! -d "${from}" && echo " Wrong dir ${from}" && exit 1
test ! -d "${to}" && echo " Wrong dir ${to}" && exit 1
test ! -d "${keyfiledir}" && echo " Wrong dir ${keyfiledir}" && exit 1

for keyfile in ${keyfiledir}/*; do
   key="${keyfile##*/}"
   find $from -type f | sed 's#.*/##' | while read -r file; do
      echo "${file}" | grep -q -f "${keyfiledir}"/"${key}" && mv "${from}"/"${file}" "${to}"/"${key}"
   done
done

echo "Not moved"
ls ${from}
echo "Moved"
ls -R ${to}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple combination of `mv` and `egrep` should suffice.  `egrep` can take a pattern list from a file (and then you get to use full regexp syntax, not just glob syntax.)  Make sure to exclude the name of the target folder.

```
cd /home/nick/TwitterSearchToDatabase/queries_for_amita
mv $(ls | egrep -f patterns.txt | grep -v '^feminism$') feminism
```